# Indian working in Canada has income in US (Sold shares) - How to file taxes/file for extension?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I am an indian citizen working in Canada on work permit. For year 2012 I was never in the US. The only income I had in US is when I sold shares + some small interest in savings account. I am neither a US citizen nor resident alien, how do I file for an extension? do I file form 4868 or 2350 or some other form?

Answer (score 1):

You can file for the extension with form 4868. You will be filing (I'm guessing) 1040NR, so read the instructions to that form in order to estimate your tax liability. You do not qualify for form 2350, as it is intended for US citizens/tax residents who need more time for specific treatment of their foreign income.

You're a bit late, but I hope it will be fine.